# Custom Grid Layout for RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, grid-layout

I needed a Grid Layout build like this.

[image]

I have create RecyclerView and set GridLayoutManager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imgPost"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it generates empty space. Please help me achieve this.

Comment: Use `StaggeredGridLayout` for such `GridView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [StaggeredGridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

Try this -

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, 1);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Added some code to explain how to work with Staggered Grid Layout, thanks